# Incorrect Integer Value SQL

Tags: integer, runtime-error, popsql

I am new to SQL and using PopSQL for editing, I incourtered to an error "Incorrect Integer Value" while connecting the database with .csv file. After some search I came to know that maybe the column is string and I am using INT command for it. But the column is ID and has numbers stored in it. I try to convert the ID column into integer and its is converted and the error remains the same. I don't know what to do.

I try to convert the ID column into integer and its is converted and the error remains the same. I don't know what to do.

Comment: If the ID number has too many digits it will not fit in all Integer types.   This depends on the SQL engine, but the sizes are usually 1 to 8 bytes.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html#:~:text=TINYINT%2C%20MEDIUMINT%2C%20BIGINT-,11.1.2%20Integer%20Types%20(Exact%20Value)%20%2D%20INTEGER%2C,TINYINT%20%2C%20MEDIUMINT%20%2C%20and%20BIGINT%20.  If the ID is too long you must store it as a string